# API server block request from GuzzleHttp

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle, blocked

I have 2 servers which are `API server` and `Client server` ....

Both server using Google Cloud server and I use Laravel framework to develop my system...

So, currently the problem is, it return `403` error when calling API (to API server) using GuzzleHttp (from `Client Server`).....

But after I change the `user agent` to `curl/7.65.3`, suddenly it is working fine...

But I want to know why??? Is there any other solution without changing the `user-agent`???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is your use method? If GET you can refer to:

GET Requests That Include a Body

If a viewer GET request includes a body, CloudFront returns an HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) to the viewer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html